# Using AngularJS 1.2, how to animate items inside partials (when using single ng-view in your index file)?

Tags: angularjs

I had an app that I got 80% through building a few weeks back and it uses a lot of jQuery to do animations.   I stopped working on that and started rebuilding it from scratch using AngularJS.

I'm now at the point where I'd like to try to add some of the animations that I WAS using in the old app.  When leaving from the "main page" to the "details page", I used to have one div go flying offscreen to the left, while the main table seemed to shrink upwards and sort of "merge with" a drop-down box that was coming into view for that new details page. (The table and the drop-down have essentially the same information, which is why the animation made sense.  The drop-down allows them to jump from record to record, without having to go back to the main table to navigate.)

Anyways, the way I built this app in Angular is that it is working off of one index file with a single "ng-view" div in it.  And then the router determines what template-page to pull in.

I see from the various tutorials out there on animating with AngularJS 1.2 that the "ng-view" fires off events that can be harnessed for animation.  But that's ONLY if you're going to add your .css class to be animated to the div that holds the "ng-view".

```
<div class='whatever' ng-view>
```

and then your css would contain something like:

```
.whatever.ng-enter{
     opacity: 0;
}
```

But what can I do if I want to animate the way various PIECES of a view template enter or leave the view?  (Most are just divs that act as containers for small tables of data [ as divs, not tables].)  I'm using "ng-repeat" in those templates to populate the tables, but I really don't want to animate any of the rows.  That's about the only other directive that fires Angular's animation that I'm currently using in the templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set animations to different parts of your template in it's controller using Jquery itself.

```
myApp.controller('sampleController', function($scope, $timeout, $location){

   $("#submit_button").click(function(){

      $("#yourdiv").fadeOut();

      $timeout(function() { $location.path('/newurl'); }, 3000);
   });

});
```

Display all your animations then change the route. I have used $timeout so as to set a delay for displaying the animations.